# Combining Expressions for LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a big code chunk below, the actual code is not that important, but is included in order to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

I have a public static Expression> GetFreeSpotCount(...)

this method returns an Expression which I would like to reuse in another method

The expression itself return a number which indicates the number of [model] in a list of [model] which fulfills certain criteria.

I want the new method to return all [model]'s where the number above is greater than 0.

below is what code I have presently, I want to avoid having to duplicate so much code

```
public static Expression<Func<ExamTimeSlot, int>> GetFreeSpotCountFor(List<Guid> drivingSchoolIds)
{
    return ets =>
    ets.Participants
        - ets.Exams.Where(ex => ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Count(e => !ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Any(r => r.DrivingSchoolId == e.BookedByDrivingSchoolId))
        - ((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Sum(r => (ets.Exams.Where(ex => ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Where(e => e.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == r.DrivingSchoolId).Count()
            - r.ReservedSpots) > 0 ? (ets.Exams.Where(ex => ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Where(e => e.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == r.DrivingSchoolId).Count() - r.ReservedSpots) : 0) ?? 0)
        - ((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Sum(r => r.ReservedSpots) ?? 0)
        + ((((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Where(r => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => r.DrivingSchoolId == id)).Sum(r => r.ReservedSpots) ?? 0)
            - ets.Exams.Where(ex => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => ex.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == id) && ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Count()) >= 0 ?
                (((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Where(r => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => r.DrivingSchoolId == id)).Sum(r => r.ReservedSpots) ?? 0)
                - ets.Exams.Where(ex => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => ex.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == id) && ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Count())
                : 0);
}
```

and:

```
public static Expression<Func<ExamTimeSlot, bool>> GetExamTimeSlotsWithFreeSpotsFor(List<Guid> drivingSchoolIds)
{
    return ets =>
    (ets.Participants
        - ets.Exams.Where(ex => ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Count(e => !ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Any(r => r.DrivingSchoolId == e.BookedByDrivingSchoolId))
        - ((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Sum(r => (ets.Exams.Where(ex => ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Where(e => e.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == r.DrivingSchoolId).Count()
            - r.ReservedSpots) > 0 ? (ets.Exams.Where(ex => ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Where(e => e.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == r.DrivingSchoolId).Count() - r.ReservedSpots) : 0) ?? 0)
        - ((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Sum(r => r.ReservedSpots) ?? 0)
        + ((((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Where(r => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => r.DrivingSchoolId == id)).Sum(r => r.ReservedSpots) ?? 0)
            - ets.Exams.Where(ex => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => ex.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == id) && ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Count()) >= 0 ?
                (((int?)ets.ExamTimeSlotReservations.Where(r => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => r.DrivingSchoolId == id)).Sum(r => r.ReservedSpots) ?? 0)
                - ets.Exams.Where(ex => drivingSchoolIds.Any(id => ex.BookedByDrivingSchoolId == id) && ex.Status == ExamStatus.Pending).Count())
                : 0)) > 0;
}
```

I wanted to do something like:

```
public static Expression<Func<ExamTimeSlot, bool>> GetExamTimeSlotsWithFreeSpotsFor(List<Guid> drivingSchoolIds)
{
    return ets => GetFreeSpotCountFor(drivingSchoolIds) > 0;
}
```

I have tried using Expression.GreaterThan with the first expression, but since I need the result AND [model] I could not figure out a way to make it work.

Comment: you're not supposed to use ` to escape code (that's for single class names in a chunk of text for example) use proper code formating instead (ident each line with 4 spaces) so that we get proper code view with formating from now on (going to edit it for you but keep it in mind for next time)

Comment: Ah the joys of stackoverflow speed, someone else fixed it in the last 13 seconds lol

Comment: Thanks, I missed the part about the indent, will make sure to use that in the future.

Comment: I'd venture that you need to take this exercise one step further and break up the logic in that fearsome looking lambda into more digestible chunks. I'd be very worried about the maintenance of such a monolithic Winnebago of logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't really an easier way (without a third party library) to do this. It seems like we *should* easily be able to do what you've written, but we're mislead because of the syntactic sugar we rely on when creating expression trees.

```
public static Expression<Func<ExamTimeSlot, bool>> GetExamTimeSlotsWithFreeSpotsFor(List<Guid> drivingSchoolIds)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(ExamTimeSlot));

    //We want to create a new lambda which will invoke `GetFreeSpotCountFor` with our parameter, and then check it's greater than 0
    var newBody = 
        Expression.GreaterThan(
            //View this as GetFreeSpotCountFor(drivingSchoolIds)(param) - where param will be given to us when this lambda is invoked
            Expression.Invoke(
                GetFreeSpotCountFor(drivingSchoolIds),
                param
            ),
            //Pass the right-hand value (0) to the GreaterThan check
            Expression.Constant(0)
        );

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ExamTimeSlot, bool>>(newBody, param);
    return lambda;
}
```

Once we've got the `Expression` object, we need to build the expression trees manually.

The above will wrap your lambda in a new lambda, which invokes and compares the result to 0. An alternative is to check the existing lambda's `.Body`, and append `.GreaterThan` to it, and return an entirely new lambda.

Ie:

```
public static Expression<Func<ExamTimeSlot, bool>> GetExamTimeSlotsWithFreeSpotsFor(List<Guid> drivingSchoolIds)
{
    //This grabs the existing lambda, which we will work on
    var oldLambda = GetFreeSpotCountFor(drivingSchoolIds);
    var newBody = 
        //Invoke `GreaterThan` directly on the old lambda's Body
        Expression.GreaterThan(
            oldLambda.Body,
            //Pass the right-hand value (0) to the GreaterThan check
            Expression.Constant(0)
        );

    //Now, we need to pass in the old parameters, and build a new lambda.
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<ExamTimeSlot, bool>>(newBody, oldLambda.Parameters);
    return lambda;
}
```

Comment: Amazing, this solved the problem exactly as I had hoped. In my hours of trying I actually came across something like the solution, but the `oldLambda.Paramenters` was what I was missing.
Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Peterbom No worries mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you specifically want to combine the expressions instead of combining the query calls? One simple way to do this would be to make your GetExamTimeSlotsWithFreeSpotsFor not take and return an expression but take and return a query, and add two where clauses to that query (each being the expression you stored).

```
  public static IQueryable<ExamTimeSlot> WhereExamTimeSlotsWithFreeSpotsFor (IQueryable<ExamTimeSlot> Source, List<Guid> drivingSchoolIds)
  {
       var FirstFilter = GetFreeSpotCountFor(drivingSchoolIds);
       var SecondFilter = GetExamTimeSlotsWithFreeSpotsFor(drivingSchoolIds);
       return Source
              .Where(FirstFilter)
              .Where(SecondFilter);                   
  }
```

That way you don't need to combine anything, let your LINQ provider combine the two where clause by himself.

Note that if you really wanted to combine the expressions manually it is possible but as far as i know it will require either a third party API or working with expression trees directly (not just enjoying the compiler magic doing it for you). It's not hard if it's just to return an expression that takes 2 expressions and tosses an and operator in between but that seems overkill for the same result.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, I picked the solution above since it was nearest to what I originally had in mind, but this might have worked too.

Comment: @Peterbom Just keep in mind that a good provider will compile .Where(A).Where(B) to the same SQL as .Where(A&B), it's a matter of taste but i think avoiding going into expression tree building is easier for other to maintains as few people are comfortable with that side of the API. Nothing wrong with it but not the solution i'd personnally pick.